# Add comma between state abb. and zip code in list of addresses

Tags: java

I believe the regex would be `"[A-Z]{2} [0-9]{5}"`. How would I go through the list and add a comma between the two? Between the state abbreviation and the zip code.

Should I find where the regex is and then just add a comma at index 2?

Comment: As you've used the words "state" and "zipcode" (as opposed to "postcode"), I'm guessing these are meant to be U.S. zipcodes? If so, they aren't seven digits long. They're either five digits (91234) or five and four (91234-5678).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it depends on location, we have 6 digits

Comment: What have you tried? What form is the list in? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @Abu: Sorry, the combination of the words "state" and "zipcode" (as opposed to "post code") made me think U.S.

Comment: If your state is always 2 characters long, why not add a tab at position 3 (index 2) and don't use regex?

Comment: There is differentiating information within each address line. It could show the street number or name or neither. It changes.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the list of strings always has an abbreviation and a post code at the end of each string, you can loop through the list and call this, using the return value to replace the existing string.

```
public String addComma(String address) {
    String[] tmp = address.split(" ");
    String newAddress = "";
    int len = tmp.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 2; i++) {
        //add all the information before the state abbreviation and post code
        newAddress = newAddress + tmp[i] + " ";
    }
    return (newAddress + tmp[len - 2] + ", " + tmp[len - 1]);
}
```